# Android OutOfMemoryError with Base64 and Google Protobuf

Tags: android, base64, out-of-memory, arrays, protocol-buffers

I am using Google protobuf to store the data into SQLite and with use of SyncAdapter app send data to server periodically.

I am converting the byte array to String using Base64.

```
/**
     * @param context
     * @param payLoad
     */
    public static void saveData(final Context context, byte[] payLoad) {
        try {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                final String deviceEncodedString = Base64.encodeToString(payLoad, Base64.DEFAULT);
                final ContentValues deviceContentValues = new ContentValues();
                deviceContentValues.put(DatabaseHelper.KEY_DATA, deviceEncodedString);
                context.getContentResolver().insert(CONTENT_URI, deviceContentValues);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

While sending it to server I am decoding it and at that time I am getting below error.

```
byte[] payload = null;
try {
     payload = Base64.decode(journalBase64.getJournal(), Base64.DEFAULT);
} catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
     Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
} catch (Exception e) {
     Logger.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Error Log :-

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 144 byte allocation with 8388608 free bytes and 316MB until OOM; failed due to fragmentation (required continguous free 16384 bytes for a new buffer where largest contiguous free 12288 bytes)
       at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:171)
       at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:136)
       at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:118)
       at co.pointwise.android.sdk.sync.SynchAdapter.onPerformSync(SynchAdapter.java:80)
       at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run(AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:259)
```

Comment: Have you tried adding android:largeHeap="true" into AndroidManifest?

Comment: 'While sending it to server I am decoding it..'. So your client first encodes to base64 and then decodes it just before sending? Why such a construction?

Comment: @OrkunKoçyiğit Yes, largeHeap is already added into manifest.

Comment: You have memory leak. Read about it and detect yours. It can be everywhere, not in this snipped.